# Semiprime number test in Haskell

Tags: haskell, numbers, benchmarking

While investigating the [Arecibo message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message) I tried to implement [*semiprimality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) tests in Haskell. I've come up with two versions:

```
isSemiprime1 :: Int -> Bool
isSemiprime1 n = (length factors) == 2 && (product factors) == n ||
                (length factors) == 1 && (head factors) ^ 2 == n
                    where factors = primeFactors n

isSemiprime2 :: Int -> Bool
isSemiprime2 n =
            case (primeFactors n) of
              [f1, f2] -> f1 * f2 == n
              [f] -> f ^ 2 == n
              otherwise -> False
```

I ran some benchmarks using `defaultMain` (from the package [`Criterion.Main`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-0.5.0.10/docs/Criterion-Main.html)) and `isSemiprime2` turned out slightly faster. Can you think of some more clever implementations, cause I don't think this is the cream of the crop :). I'm specifically interested in concise, heavily functional implementations.

Also, if anyone is interested, here's my code for benchmarking:

```
main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain [
        bgroup "isSemiprime1" [ bench "169" $ whnf isSemiprime1 169
                              , bench "1679" $ whnf isSemiprime1 1679
                              ],
        bgroup "isSemiprime2" [ bench "169" $ whnf isSemiprime2 169
                              , bench "1679" $ whnf isSemiprime2 1679
                              ]
       ]
```

Comment: `isSemiprime2` _should_ be faster - and if you use bigger numbers, the speed difference will become quite drastic. Regardless, I possit that `primeFactors` is where most of the time is being spent.

Comment: I would expect `primeFactors` to generate repeated primes, i.e. `primeFactors 4` is `[2, 2]`, so you don't need the square case. And if `primeFactors` generates the list lazily, `isSemiprime2` is certainly a lot faster since it can take the `otherwise` branch when the 3rd factor is found.

Comment: By the way, why not `f*f` instead of `f^2`  ?

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher, thanks for the suggestion. Ingo, you're right. Although SjoerdVisscher's comment obviates that case altogether.

Comment: @Ingo: because it looks uglier and has no relevant advantage? (It's equivalent, being implemented _in terms of `*`_, safe for performance considerations, which doesn't matter here though because much more work is already done at that point anyway.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Well, I thought this is about performance ... concerning uglier is a matter of taste, though ... someone with a C background might think: Why does he flip the second least significant bit here?

Comment: Someone with a C background _might_ think so, but they might also wonder why you multiply with a dereferenced pointer in `e ** x`, or use bitwise `OR` to build up guards. It's perfectly obvious in this case that we want exponentiation, in particular as the line above has `f1 * f2` (which BTW, is quite an argument to write `f * f` after all – in particular, if you align the `*` in both lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two functions you listed have the same performance since they both use `primeFactors` where most of the time is spent. If you look at the implementation it's just doing trial division with successive numbers generated from the sieve. This is not the most efficient method.

If you want faster code you should use a better factorization algorithm. For example:

```
import Math.NumberTheory.Primes.Factorisation

isSemiprime3 :: Integer -> Bool
isSemiprime3 n = (length factors) == 2 && (product factors) == n ||
                (length factors) == 1 && (head factors) ^ 2 == n
                    where factors = map fst $ factorise n
```

results in:

```
....
benchmarking isSemiprime1/557672900621
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 13.84439 s
mean: 138.4969 ms, lb 138.3753 ms, ub 138.7278 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 830.8696 us, lb 505.2076 us, ub 1.301439 ms, ci 0.950

benchmarking isSemiprime3/557672900621
mean: 5.315161 ms, lb 5.292123 ms, ub 5.397730 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 198.7367 us, lb 59.15932 us, ub 453.7225 us, ci 0.950
found 5 outliers among 100 samples (5.0%)
  3 (3.0%) high mild
  2 (2.0%) high severe
variance introduced by outliers: 33.631%
variance is moderately inflated by outliers

benchmarking isSemiprime2/557672900621
collecting 100 samples, 1 iterations each, in estimated 13.85570 s
mean: 138.9948 ms, lb 138.8015 ms, ub 139.3493 ms, ci 0.950
std dev: 1.302262 ms, lb 844.1709 us, ub 2.330201 ms, ci 0.950
```

**5 ms vs. 138 ms**

Comment: this is an impressive speedup! Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a look at the implementation.

Comment: Hmm, I see that this method has the performance difference much more pronounced for large numbers. Tested with smaller numbers (like 1679) the speedup is of the order of 5. I definitely must look more closely into the method. Thanks again for the idea.

Comment: For small numbers I would expect `Math.NumberTheory.Primes.Factorisation` to actually be slower.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code to find semiPrime between a to b, is not the best, but works, was for a interview in js

```
function findSemiprimes(rangeStart, rangeEnd) {
  let inicio = rangeStart
  let final = rangeEnd
  if (final < inicio) {
    inicio = rangeEnd
    final = rangeStart
  }
  let primos = []
  for (let i = 1; i <= final; i++) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      primos.push(i)
    }
  }

  let semiPrimos = []

  for (const primo of primos) {
    let primos2 = []
    for (let i = 2; i <= primo; i++) {
      if (isPrime(i)) primos2.push(i)
    }
    for (const primo2 of primos2) {
      let posible = primo * primo2
      if (posible <= final) {
        if (semiPrimos.indexOf(posible) <= 0) {
          semiPrimos.push(posible)
        }
      }
    }

  }

  semiPrimos.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  })
  semiPrimos = semiPrimos.filter(primo => primo >= inicio)
  return semiPrimos
}


function isPrime(num) {
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i === 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return num !== 1;
}

function main() {
  const result = findSemiprimes(20, 100);
  console.log("result:", result)
}

main()
```